# Xamarin error when building in release mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build my Xamarin application in release mode, but I'm getting the error:

```
 "Error     Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.AttributeProvider::GetTypeDescriptor(System.Type)' in assembly: 'EntityFramework.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider::.ctor(System.Type)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   en MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   en Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   en Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   en MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   en Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() en /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:línea 17 proyecto.Android                Compilación
".
```

This error only occurs in release mode, it doesn't appear in debug mode. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: You can try to set the `Liner ` to `none` and try again. For more information, check document [Linking on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker).